# React.Component - reuse component created by `new` operator

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, I was wondering if we reuse an already created `React.Component` (by `new` operator) inside `render` method. For example -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script src="react.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
        <script src="react-dom.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
        <script src="babel.7.5.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br>
        <h3>Enter number in box for multiplication.</h3>
        <br>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

            class ResultComp extends React.Component{
                constructor(props){
                    super(props)
                    this.state = {valueOne : 0, valueTwo : 0, product : 0}
                }
                render(){
                    console.log("ResultComp : render")
                    return(
                        <div>Result = {this.state.product}</div>
                    )
                }
            }

            class MyApp extends React.Component{
                render(){
                    console.log("MyApp : render")
                    var alreadyCreatedComponent = new ResultComp()
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <ResultComp id="0"/>
                            <alreadyCreatedComponent id="2"/> 
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }

            ReactDOM.render(
                <MyApp/>,
                document.getElementById("container")
            )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here - `<ResultComp id="0"/>` is working.

But, can we make something like `<alreadyCreatedComponent id="2"/>`?

I need to do this, because I need to pass the same `alreadyCreatedComponent` to some other function.

Comment: Yes, sorry typo

Answer (score 1):

This is what React JS is for. You don't need the following:

```
var alreadyCreatedComponent = new ResultComp()
```

Instead, what you can do is:

```js
return (
    <div>
        <ResultComp id="0"/>
        <ResultComp id="2"/> 
        <br/>
    </div>
);
```

But if you want to use the same state values, you have to step the states location up in the parent component and pass them as props.

That's the reusing of components in React JS.

Comment: I need to do this, because I need to pass the same alreadyCreatedComponent to some other function.

Comment: @CRSardar Looks like you are doing something wrong. You have an XY Problem. What you have done is great till now. What exactly you want to do, let me try to help you.

Comment: @CRSardar Tell me if [this snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dewdney-1nl81) works like you want?

Comment: This is working fine -
https://github.com/crsardar/HandsOnWebTech/blob/master/react-webpages/react-component-interaction.html

Comment: But, every time it is re-rendering everything starting from `MyApp`, as I am changing state of `MyApp`.
I want it should only re-render `ResultComp`.
So, I was thinking something like -  https://github.com/crsardar/HandsOnWebTech/blob/master/react-webpages/react-component-interaction-optimized-rendering.html

Comment: @CRSardar Not sure if you are learning React the right way, I suggest you courses by WesBos. That line doesn't come anywhere in React reusing using `new` operator.